# std::move doesn't work when the derived class' destructor is specified

Tags: c++

I was trying to move an instance to another one, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

class student {
public:
    student() = default;
    student(const student& student) {
        std::cout << "copy student" << std::endl;
    }
    student(student&& student) {
        std::cout << "move student" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~student() = default;
};

class undergraduate: public student {
public:
    undergraduate(): student() {}
    ~undergraduate() override = default; // removing this line will make std::move work
};

int main() {
    undergraduate student;
    undergraduate student1 = std::move(student);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
copy student
```

As you can see, `std::move` didn't work, `student` was copied instead of moved, however, if I remove `undergraduate`'s destructor, i.e. the following line:

```
~undergraduate() override = default; // removing this line will make std::move work
```

The output will become `move student`, which means `std::move` works. Why? Why didn't `std::move` work when the derived class' destructor is specified?

Comment: You wrote a move constructor but not a matching move assignment operator. Why not?

Comment: `std::move` always work. In can't not work, it is a cast in disguise. The question is, why move constructor is not called - which is answered below.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Because move constructor is used here instead of move assignment. Move constructor is called when an object is initialized, like `T a = std::move(b);` or `T a(std::move(b));`, check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor for more details.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Specifying a class's destructor inhibits automatic generation of the move constructor and move assignment. You can restore them by using `= default`:

```
class undergraduate: public student {
public:
    undergraduate(): student() {}
    ~undergraduate() override = default;

    undergraduate(const undergraduate&) = default;
    undergraduate& operator=(const undergraduate&) = default;

    undergraduate(undergraduate&&) = default;
    undergraduate& operator=(undergraduate&&) = default;
};
```

Howard Hinnant created an excellent table for his *Everything You Ever Wanted To Know About Move Semantics (and then some)"* presentation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that table! Mind if I save and use intensively?

Comment: @YSC: I take no credit for the table, it was made by Howard Hinnant.

Comment: The slides from the host: https://accu.org/content/conf2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf

Comment: The easier to remember rule: `=default` or `=delete` or implement the 5 special member functions whenever you touch any of them.